# Tutoring as a undergrad student

Tags: undergraduate, tutoring

My school provides undergrad students with the opportunity to tutor the classes where they received an A as an extra-curricular program. I have received an A+ in some classes and think that if I have a chance to be a tutor of that class, it will help enhance  my understanding and teaching skills.  However, tutoring is so time-consuming that if I do it, I might give up one of the lectures next semester.

So, my question is: Is it worthwhile to be a tutor if I want to go to grad school?

Comment: What does "as extra-curricular program" mean? Does this imply you are not getting paid?

Comment: @PVAL Yes. It's just counted as a volunteering or if I want, I could get 1 credit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tutoring is definitely a great way to gain more confidence and knowledge in a certain area as well as help you to decide if you enjoy the subject/teaching it and want to go to grad school. However, it sounds like you know the class really well as you received an A+ and it isn't worth dropping a lecture just to tutor. Grad schools do not put nearly as much weight on tutoring to warrant sacrificing other things that would benefit you.